# no matching constructor for initialization of 'vlq'

Tags: c++

I'm getting `no known conversion from 'vlq' to 'uint32_t'` (compile log below) when compiling the following code:

```
// vlq.h

#ifndef __VARIABLE_LENGTH_QUANTITY_H__
#define __VARIABLE_LENGTH_QUANTITY_H__

#include <memory>

class vlq {
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> valueBytes; // pointer to value
        size_t valueLength; // length of value

        static size_t encodedLength(uint32_t a);
        static uint8_t* encodeVlq(uint32_t a);  
        static uint32_t decodeVlq(uint8_t* valueBytes, size_t valueLength);
    public:
        vlq(); // defualt constructor
        vlq(uint32_t value);

        size_t length() const; // returns number of bytes to store vlq
        uint32_t value() const; // returns encoded value of vlq

        vlq operator+ (vlq const &obj);
};

#endif
```

```
// vlq.cpp

#include "vlq.h"
#include <stdexcept> // std::out_of_range
#include <stdint.h>  // uint8_t, uint32_t
#include <cmath>     // log2, floor

vlq::vlq() {
    this->valueBytes.reset();
    this->valueLength = 0;
}

vlq::vlq(uint32_t value) {
    size_t valueLength = encodedLength(value);
    uint8_t* valueBytes = encodeVlq(value);
    this->valueBytes.reset(valueBytes);
    this->valueLength = valueLength;
}

// returns required length for passed value
size_t vlq::encodedLength(uint32_t a) {
    // calculate number of bits required
    size_t numBits = std::floor(std::log2(a)) + 1;

    // set length
    size_t length;
    if (numBits % 7 == 0) {
        length = numBits / 7;
    } else {
        length = numBits / 7 + 1;
    }

    return length;
}

// encodes bytes of a vlq
uint8_t* vlq::encodeVlq(uint32_t a) {
    size_t length = encodedLength(a);

    uint8_t *formattedVlqBytes = new uint8_t[length];

    // turn a into 7 bit chunks
    int chunkOffset;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        chunkOffset = (length - i - 1) * 7;

        formattedVlqBytes[i] = (a & (0x7F << chunkOffset)) >> chunkOffset;

        // set bit if this isn't the last bit
        if (i != length - 1) {
            formattedVlqBytes[i] |= 0x80;
        }
    }

    return formattedVlqBytes;
}

// decodes bytes of a vlq
uint32_t vlq::decodeVlq(uint8_t* valueBytes, size_t valueLength) {
    size_t numBits = valueLength * 7;

    uint32_t decodedVlq = 0x0;

    size_t byteOffset, bitOffset;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numBits; i++) {
        byteOffset = i / 7;
        bitOffset = 6 - (i % 7);

        decodedVlq |= valueBytes[byteOffset] & (0x1 << bitOffset) << (valueLength - byteOffset - 1) * 7;
    }

    return decodedVlq;
}

// returns encoded value of vlq
uint32_t vlq::value() const {
    return decodeVlq(this->valueBytes.get(), this->valueLength);
}

vlq vlq::operator+(vlq const &obj) {
    uint32_t sum = this->value() + obj.value();

    return vlq(sum);
}
```

```
// compiler output

vlq.cpp:81:9: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'vlq'
        return vlq(sum);
               ^~~~~~~~
./vlq.h:6:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument
class vlq {
      ^
vlq.cpp:11:6: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'vlq' to 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') for 1st argument
vlq::vlq(uint32_t value) {
     ^
vlq.cpp:6:6: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
vlq::vlq() {
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Why am I getting `no known conversion from 'vlq' to 'uint32_t'` when passing a `uint32_t`?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this when compiling with either g++ or clang++ on my machine, and I'm able to exercise the class including `operator+` in my own testcase. Would you be able to tell us more details about your setup and any compiler flags you are passing?

Comment: You are trying to return `vlq` by value, but `vlq` is not copyable due to `unique_ptr` member. This works with C++17 and later due to guaranteed copy elision; apparently, you use a pre-C++17 compiler.

Comment: `#ifndef __VARIABLE_LENGTH_QUANTITY_H__` <-- Note that identifiers starting with underscore followed by a capital letter, as well as identifiers containing double underscores anywhere, are *reserved for the implementation*. You are *not* allowed to use such identifiers in your own code.